# Inputing info in forms, then recalling it via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 3 divs that show one after another.

The first div shows three pictures, you choose which you like best by clicking the link below the picture, which also takes you to div 2.

Div 2 is a bunch of input boxes and a drop down selector. Once you fill out all the forms, click the next link which takes you to div 3.

Div 3 is a review of what you selected. It should show what picture you selected in div 1, and what you put in the text boxes / selector in div 2.

I have no idea how to go about doing this, and im really struggling, any and all help is appreciated.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7yuuz8d4/27/

```js
/* JS - */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#div1').show();
  $('#div2').hide();
  $('#div3').hide();
    
  $('#div1').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
  });
    
  $('#div2').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
  });
});
            
    /*$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#div1').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                    var stylechoice = $(this).attr('value');
                });
       $("#height").prop(function(){
           var height = $('#height').prop('value);
         });
            });
       */

     /*$(document).ready(function () {
                    if(document.getElement
                });
           */

    /*if(document.getElementById('.col-md-4').clicked) {
        $("#casual").show("#style1");
    } else if {
        $("#street").show("#style1");
    } else if {
        $("#classic").show("#style1");
    });*/
```

```html
<!-- Html --> 

<!doctype html>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
     <div class="container">
      <div id="div1">
         <h2>Pick your style</h2>
            
        
    
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="casual">Casual &raquo;</a>
        </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="street">Street &raquo;</a>
        </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="classic">Classic &raquo;</a>
        </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
     </div><!--Closes div1-->
       
        <div id="div2">
        <h3>Measurements</h3>
        <h5>Measurements can be in inches or centimeters, just please notate which you use</h5>
             <form>
                  Height:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="height" id="height"><br>
                  Neck:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="neck" id="neck"><br>
                  Arms:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="arms" id="arms"><br>
                  Waist:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="waist" id="waist"><br>
                  Legs:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="legs" id="legs"><br>
                  Shoes:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="shoes" id="shoes"><br>
                  
                  Shirt size:<br>
                  <select>
                      <option value="small" id="small">Small</option>
                      <option value="medium" id="medium">Medium</option>
                      <option value="large" id="large">Large</option>
                      <option value="xlarge" id="xlarge">X-Large</option>
                      <option value="xxlarge" id="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
              </select> 
            </form> 
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div3" role="button">Next &raquo;</a>
        </div><!--Closes div2-->
        
        
        <div id="div3">
        <h3>Review</h3>
        <p>Here's the info you gave us, please double check it:</p>
        <p>Style:</p>
        <p>Height:</p>
        <p>Neck:</p>
        <p>Arms:</p>
        <p>Waist:</p>
        <p>Legs:</p>
        <p>Shoes:</p>
        <p>Shirt size:</p>
        <p>Finally, any notes for our fashion aids?</p>
         <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="100">
     Any other concerns you have we should know about? Do you have big thighs, long neck, big arms, etc. anything and anything that can help with the fitting of your clothing is extremely helpful!
     </textarea>
        <div id="display">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="success.html" role="button">Submit &raquo;</a>
        </div>
        
        </div><!--Closes div3-->
        </div><!--Closes container-->
        
</body>
```

Note: I commented out what i have been trying to work on, and failing with. I have the `div` show/hide jquery working, im just putting it in here so that you know what i have so far, and that the solution anybody provides doesnt break that code in the meantime.

Comment: Seems like the fiddle is working fine; just that you dint include jQuery reference in the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7yuuz8d4/28/

Comment: Your code works perfectly in your Fiddle. **You just need to include JQuery file** - If you check the browser console, it tells you

Comment: I dont think you guys read my post. The fiddle works for hiding/showing divs, thats not what im asking for help with. I need to recall what picture was selected, and what was typed into the forms in divs 1-2 and output that info in div3's corresponding lines.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer I have post a generic solution below. If you are interested, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should get you started:

https://jsfiddle.net/xszmdx3a/

Create some empty tags in your third div to hold the content:

```
<p>Style:<span id="style-d3"></span></p>
<p>Height: <span id="height-d3"></span></p>
```

I added an extra class to your links in the first div:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg picture-link" href="#div2" role="button" value="casual">Casual &raquo;</a>
```

And then add an event handler for the image:

```
        $('.picture-link').click(function() {
            var imgTag = $(this).parent().find('img')[0];
          $(imgTag).clone().appendTo('#style-d3');
        });
```

Similarly for the other fields:

```
        $('#height').change(function() {
            $('#height-d3').html($(this).val());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the value of a textbox (and most other form controls) using the jQuery `.val()` function.

e.g. in your case:

```
var waistVal = $("#waist").val();
```

If you want to re-display the value elsewhere, then you could create an element, such as `<div>` or `<span>` to contain the value, and then inject the new value into it, e.g.:

```
<p>Waist:</p><span id="waistVal"></span>
```

So instead of the above jQuery script, you could instead write:

```
    $("#waistVal").text($("#waist").val());
```

which will immediately show the value of the "waist" textbox inside the "waistVal" span. You can do the same for all the other textboxes and the dropdown.

Secondly, for the style links, it's probably more user-friendly to make the image itself clickable (and just have the words as labels only):

HTML in div1:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png" value="street">
Street
```

HTML in div3:

```
<p>Style:</p><span id="styleVal"></span><span id="styleImg"></span>
```

jQuery (inside the click event for the first set of hyperlinks):

```
$('#div1').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
  //this will be populated, but invisible until div3 is displayed
  $("#styleVal").text($(this).attr("value"));
  $(this).clone().appendTo("#styleImg");
  $("#div1").hide();
  $"(#div2").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this generic solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div1').show();
            $('#div2').hide();
            $('#div3').hide();
            
            var data = {
             'div1': {},
              'div2': {}
            };

            $('#div1').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
              var imgTag = $(this).parent().find('img')[0];
               data.div1.src = $(imgTag).attr('src');
              
                $('#div1').hide();
                $('#div2').show();
            });

            $('#div2').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
              $(this).parent().find('form input, form select').each(function(){
                 data.div2[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
                });
            
                $('#div2').hide();
                $('#div3').show();
                                                                    
                setValues();
            });
            
            function setValues(){
              $('#style-d3').append('<img src="' + data.div1.src + '">');
               $.each(data.div2, function(key, val){
                $('#' + key + '-d3').text(val);
               });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div id="div1">
     <h2>Pick your style</h2>
        
    

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg picture-link" href="#div2" role="button" value="casual">Casual &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg picture-link" href="#div2" role="button" value="street">Street &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg picture-link" href="#div2" role="button" value="classic">Classic &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
 </div><!--Closes div1-->
   
    <div id="div2">
    <h3>Measurements</h3>
    <h5>Measurements can be in inches or centimeters, just please notate which you use</h5>
         <form>
              Height:<br>
              <input type="text" name="height" id="height"><br>
              Neck:<br>
              <input type="text" name="neck" id="neck"><br>
              Arms:<br>
              <input type="text" name="arms" id="arms"><br>
              Waist:<br>
              <input type="text" name="waist" id="waist"><br>
              Legs:<br>
              <input type="text" name="legs" id="legs"><br>
              Shoes:<br>
              <input type="text" name="shoes" id="shoes"><br>
              
              Shirt size:<br>
              <select name="size">
                  <option value="small" id="small">Small</option>
                  <option value="medium" id="medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="large" id="large">Large</option>
                  <option value="xlarge" id="xlarge">X-Large</option>
                  <option value="xxlarge" id="xxlarge">XX-Large</option>
          </select> 
        </form> 
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div3" role="button">Next &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes div2-->
    
    
    <div id="div3">
    <h3>Review</h3>
    <p>Here's the info you gave us, please double check it:</p>
    <p>Style:<span id="style-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Height: <span id="height-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Neck: <span id="neck-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Arms: <span id="arms-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Waist: <span id="waist-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Legs: <span id="legs-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Shoes: <span id="shoes-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Shirt size: <span id="size-d3"></span></p>
    <p>Finally, any notes for our fashion aids?</p>
     <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="100">
 Any other concerns you have we should know about? Do you have big thighs, long neck, big arms, etc. anything and anything that can help with the fitting of your clothing is extremely helpful!
 </textarea>
    <div id="display">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="success.html" role="button">Submit &raquo;</a>
    </div>
    
    </div><!--Closes div3-->
    </div><!--Closes container-->
  
    
    </body>
```